# Convention for paths of length zero?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Given some graph $G=(V,E)$ and some $v \in V$, what is the set of nodes reachable from $v$ by a path of length zero? Is it ...

1. The empty set $\emptyset $?
2. Only $v$ itself, i.e. $\{v\}$? Since we are already "at that node"?

I lean toward the first case because a node "reaching itself" usually requires at least a step of length one along a reflexive edge $(v,v)\in E$ but I am curious about other opinions / arguments and whether there is a consensus.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematicians typically add conventions in certain circumstances in order to eliminate (or at least reduce) special cases in possible proofs.  For example, the usual definition of a polynomial with coefficients { $a_i$ } as $\sum_i a_i x^i$ requires the convention that $x^0$ must always be 1, even for $x=0$.  On that basis I believe the correct convention for the path from $v$ to $w$ - if notated as '$[ v ... w]$' - in the special case where $v=w$ should be $[ v ]$ not empty (*note: I think set notation is inappropriate in this case*).